# Layout issue with visual c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, grid, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a simple WPF Application on Visual Studio 2017 (Visual C#).
I have this form:

```
<Window x:Class="HelloWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Greetings" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="192*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="86*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select a message option and then choose the Display button." VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Width="329" Margin="102,131,86,45"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbHello" Content="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="47" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbGoodbye" Content="Goodbye" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="67" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Content="Display" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="231,2,0,0" Click="Button_Click" Height="20" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this is the preview:
[image: Preview on visual studio]

When I compile this is the result in a window
[image: window]

and if I try to use fullscreen it display me this:
[image: fullscreen]

Why it do this? How can I resolve it?
(This is an example from [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/jj153219.aspx)!)

Comment: This looks like WPF, not WinForms. The link you provided is to a WPF example.

Comment: Sorry, WPF is correct, I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is WPF not windows forms. And your positioning is all wrong. When you drag and drop stuff it uses absolute positioning. If you want it on the center use  
`<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">`

But [here](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) is a good place to start learning the system

Comment: Thanks, very useful